# Deleting Data From MongoDB with Mongoose NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here is my files fetching data from mongoose

router file (working)

```
router.get('/' , function(req ,  res , next) {
ClassModel.find({}).exec(function(err , Classes) {
if(err) throw err;
res.render('classlist', { "Classes": Classes}); 
});
});
```

now passing data to view (working)

```
<% Classes.forEach(function(Class , index){%>
<tr>
<td><%= index+1. %></td>
<td><%= Class.Class_Name %></td>
<td><%= Class.Class_ID %></td>
<td><%= Class.Class_Key %></td>
<td>
 <form action="/DeleteClass" method="post"><input type="submit" value="delete"</form>
<td></tr>
<%});%>
```

now this is delete.js file not working

```
router.delete('/', function(req, res){
ClassModel.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
if(err) res.json(err);
res.render('deleteClass');
});
});
```

Comment: try changing `req.params.id` to `req.body.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to change the request method to delete in your form and add the class id to the action route :

```
<form action="/DeleteClass/<%= Class._id%>" method="delete">
  <input type="submit" value="delete"> // don't forget to close input tag
</form>
```

after, change the route to `/:id` so you can access `req.params.id` value :

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res){
   ClassModel.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
     if(err) res.json(err);
       res.render('deleteClass');
   });
});
```

Comment: this <%= Class.Class_ID %> is not that _id (object id) its like class username